# Access doc fields in trigger function

Tags: mongodb, triggers, mongodb-atlas

In the trigger function we're given the following:

```
//Access a mongodb service:
const collection = context.services.get(<SERVICE_NAME>).db("db_name").collection("coll_name");
const doc = collection.findOne({ name: "mongodb" });
// I try
return doc.name
```

Why does this result in: `$undefined": true`? How do I access the name field?